# Como añadir varias condicionantes en un IF en PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

estoy validando un menu segun el tipo de usuario, por ejemplo los campos que valido son estos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces el codigo que uso para mostrar por usuario es este

```
<?php if($tipo_usuario == 5) { ?> 

//Aca dentro coloco el menu segun el tipo de usuario, por ejemplo este solo tiene 3 menus que son Cerrar sesion, cambiar contraseña y registrar asistencia y asi varia segun el usuario

<?php } ?>
```

lo que quiero hacer es añadirle mas condiciones a esta validacion

```
<?php if($tipo_usuario == 5) { ?>
```

Por ejemplo, esta es la tabla de usuarios, entonces valida el tipo de usuario pero añadi 2 campos nuevos los cuales son **zona asignada** y **sector_asignado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que quiero es que por ejemplo si el usuario es tipo_usuario=5 , zona_asignada=1, sector_asignado=1   que me muestre un menu

si el usuario es tipo_usuario=5 , zona_asignada=1, sector_asignado=2   que me muestre otro menu y asi

No se como añadir la validacion de los campos **zona_asignada** y **sector_asignado** a este codigo

`<?php if($tipo_usuario == 5) { ?>`

Comment: prueba usar switch($var){case 1: "Código aquí"; break; ...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el operador "&&"  o  "and" (dependiendo de la version de php que estes usando).

EJemplo:

```
 <?php 
if( ($tipo_usuario == 5) && (zona_asignad == 1) && (sector_asignado == 2) ) { ?>
```

O si tienes una version mayor a 7.3

```
 <?php 
if( ($tipo_usuario == 5) and (zona_asignad == 1) and (sector_asignado == 2) ) { ?>
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

La sugerencia es usar operador lógico dado que dos condiciones se cumplen en ambas: tipo_usuario=5 y zona_asignada=1. El && es ese operador lógico que enlaza dos condiciones como que ambas tiene que ser verdaderas para que se valide.

Luego, dentro del if, colocas un switch case que evalúe la variable $sector_asignado.

```
 <?php if($tipo_usuario == 5 && $zona_asignada == 1) { 
    
       switch ($sector_asignado) {
        case 1:
            /* Menu 1*/
            break;
        case 2:
            /* Menu 2 */
            break;
       }
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: Como podria agregar el codigo del menu aca? despues del Case 1 :

El codigo seria este por ejemplo
<li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <i class="far fa-calendar"></i>
              <p>
                Calendario
                
              </p>
            </a>
          </li>